# what does musical noise sound like and is there a sample clip for it?

Tags: audio, noise, speech-processing, denoising

Musical residual noise is created when a noisy signal passes through a noise reduction algorithm. For instance, please see the paper:  [Esch, T; Vary, P: "Efficient Musical Noise Suppression for Speech Enhancement Systems", *IEEE Intl Conf Acoustics, Speech and Signal Proc*, (ICASSP): 4409-4412, 2009](http://www.ind.rwth-aachen.de/fileadmin/publications/esch09.pdf).

> Noise reduction techniques that are relying on spectral weighting
>   rules often generate annoying musical noise artifacts in the processed
>   signal.

What exactly does it sound like? Are there any sample clips available (for example, a wav file before passing through a noise reduction algorithm routine and a wav file after noise reduction with musical noise) for comparison?

Comment: Not a proper answer but low bit-rate mp3 artefacts sound very similar. There are plenty of examples of these around.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one example: http://www.izotope.com/tech/aes_suppr/

Googling "Musical Noise" certainly turns up a lot of noise music, so I'd suggest looking for academic papers that have web links to sound examples.

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples in this blog post.

http://iosr.surrey.ac.uk/blog/2013-12-16.php