# As of 2023, is it possible to extract two human voice from single audio track?

Tags: speech, voice, source-separation

[Isolation of different human voices from audio](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40346/isolation-of-different-human-voices-from-audio)

[Separate two voices from a speech signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21605/separate-two-voices-from-a-speech-signal)

Several years ago it was hard to extract voice from music and almost impossible to separate two human voices from mixed stereo or mono tracks. With AI algorithms' aid there are many services allowing separation of voice/music or even different kinds of instruments. Is is possible now to separate two human voice from one track now?

Or, two make things easier, if one singing (score provided) and one talking, how should it be done, manually or automatically, without losing too many overtones and reducing quality?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://vocalremover.org

Comment: We can only speculate about how some AI or ML or whatever algorithm does to identify different quasi-periodic tracks that are added together.  But once a pitch of a voice is correctly tracked, the pitched part of the vocal utterance can be isolated with a correctly tuned comb filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DeMIX Pro Version 4.0](https://www.audiosourcere.com/products/demix-pro-audio-separation-software) from [AudioSourceRE](https://www.audiosourcere.com/home) can separate the lead vocal from not only the backing instrumentation, it can separate the lead vocal from backing vocals **and** from harmony vocals! Highly recommended!